# Create a new page to confluence with Python

Tags: python, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to create a new page into confluence using Python. How can I embedd the use of the macro "Markdown from URL" in the page, how should I write the HTML page code to add the component?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite simple
Take a look at this plugin:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1227501/storage-format-editor-for-confluence-free?tab=overview&hosting=cloud

This will allow you to view/edit confluence source code on confluence pages.

Create a blank page, play around with macros and see how they appear in the source code for the page.
I don't have the "Markdown from URL" macro installed but it should look similar to this:
HTML Macro:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="11654ce7-4576-9875-8c96-9f6914625df7" ac:name="html" ac:schema-version="1">
  <ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[<p>Hello</p>]]></ac:plain-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

I believe the macro-id doesn't matter, you can leave it blank when inserting to confluence and it will work

You can just add this in the body of the confluence page through python